# Cannot see Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a static v4.app.Fragment in an AppCompatActivity's xml, and everything shows up when I launch the app, but once I enter another activity and comeback, or switch to another app and switch back, the fragment cannot be seen, while the Log.d of the fragment shows that the fragment exists somewhere. I have also tried using getsupportfragmentmanager.add.commit to programmatically add the fragment, and it has the same result

activity_main.xml
    ...

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.Fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
...
```

MainActivity.java

```
@BindView(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;
@BindView(R.id.fab) FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(MainActivity.this);
...
No onResume, onCreateView, etc
```

XFragment.java

```
public class XFragment extends Fragment {

@BindView(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout) SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
@BindView(R.id.recyclerView) RecyclerView recyclerView; 
// and a lot of other variables

public XFragment() {

}

public static XFragment newInstance(boolean isSearch) {
    XFragment xFragment = new XFragment();
    return xFragment;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();
    //initiate variables
    inflateRecyclerView();
    //etc
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_x, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Parcelable parcelable = llm.onSaveInstanceState();
    outState.putParcelable("LM", parcelable);
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onViewStateRestored");
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      llm = savedInstanceState.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("LM"));
    }
}

public void inflateRecyclerView() {
    //use retrofit to call api
}
```

P.S.: when I add it dynamically, I hide the , findViewById in the activity, then use

```
XFragment f = new XFragment.newInstance();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, f).commit();
```

Comment: can you post some java code?

Comment: @SlowLearner java code added. thx

Comment: I add the fragment statically in the activity_main.xml, that why I don't need to call fragment manager right? (according to https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

Comment: yea, my bad... sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know what is causing the problem. I have been using a library call DynamicBox, and it seems that it is causing the problem. I don't know if I have do something wrong or there are bugs on that library yet.
Yay...